# RuntimeException if minifyEnabled is true with ViewModel class

Tags: java, android, exception, kotlin, viewmodel

If `minifyEnabled` is `false` everything works fine. But after I change my `minifyEnabled` to `true` runtime exception happens:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.ui.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class .ui.main.MainViewModel
```

My `MainActivity` class extends `AppCompatActivity`, and implements `LifecycleRegistryOwner`, then I declare:

```
  private val lifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry by lazy { LifecycleRegistry(this) }
  private val viewModel: MainViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java) }
  override fun getLifecycle(): LifecycleRegistry = lifecycleRegistry
  // and other simple stuff
```

Should I put something in my proguard-rules file maybe?

The full exception log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.appchamp.wordchunks, PID: 32558
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appchamp.wordchunks/com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainViewModel
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainViewModel
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders$DefaultFactory.create(Unknown Source)
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(Unknown Source)
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(Unknown Source)
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.l.a(Unknown Source)
                      at a.e.a(Unknown Source)
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainActivity.c(Unknown Source)
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3216)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders$DefaultFactory.create(Unknown Source) 
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(Unknown Source) 
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(Unknown Source) 
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.l.a(Unknown Source) 
                      at a.e.a(Unknown Source) 
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainActivity.c(Unknown Source) 
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainActivity.onStart(Unknown Source) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3216) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: impossible
                      at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:45)
                      at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:35)
                      at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:54)
                      at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:211)
                      at java.util.EnumMap.initialization(EnumMap.java:738)
                      at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:391)
                      at io.realm.ad.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at io.realm.ad.a(Unknown Source)
                      at io.realm.ad.a(Unknown Source)
                      at io.realm.aa.l(Unknown Source)
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainViewModel.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders$DefaultFactory.create(Unknown Source) 
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(Unknown Source) 
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(Unknown Source) 
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.l.a(Unknown Source) 
                      at a.e.a(Unknown Source) 
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainActivity.c(Unknown Source) 
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainActivity.onStart(Unknown Source) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3216) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: values []
                      at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:630)
                      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:589)
                      at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:41)
                      at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:35) 
                      at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:54) 
                      at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:211) 
                      at java.util.EnumMap.initialization(EnumMap.java:738) 
                      at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:391) 
                      at io.realm.ad.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                      at io.realm.ad.a(Unknown Source) 
                      at io.realm.ad.a(Unknown Source) 
                      at io.realm.aa.l(Unknown Source) 
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainViewModel.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders$DefaultFactory.create(Unknown Source) 
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(Unknown Source) 
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(Unknown Source) 
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.l.a(Unknown Source) 
                      at a.e.a(Unknown Source) 
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainActivity.c(Unknown Source) 
                      at com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainActivity.onStart(Unknown Source) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3216) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)  end
```

Comment: You need to configure `proguard-rules` to keep class members. Take a look at the follow https://gist.github.com/Jackgris/c4a71328b1ae346cba04#file-proguard-rules

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix the problem by adding the following line to my `proguard-rules.pro` file.

```
-keep class * extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel { *; }
```

In my case I was using a custom ViewModelProvider, which means that my `init()` statement included a number of arguments.  If you are not using a custom ViewModelProvider you might be able to get away with the following as described in the [Android ViewModel ProGuard example file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a9ac247af2afd4115c3eb6d16c05bc92737d6305/lifecycle/viewmodel/proguard-rules.pro):

```
-keep class * extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel {
    <init>();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you make minifyEnabled to true , proguard shrinks , obfuscate your model class and Activity can't recognise it , in your pro guard-rules.pro please add below line

```
-keep class com.appchamp.wordchunks.ui.main.MainViewModel;
```

Comment: it's not the solution

Comment: @JuliaKo Can you try editing ViewModelProviders.of(this) to ViewModelProviders.of(this , viewModelFactory)

Answer (score -4):

To enable code shrinking with ProGuard, add minifyEnabled true to the appropriate build type in your build.gradle file.

the following snippet from a **build.gradle** file enables code shrinking for the release build:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```